# 'phpcs' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an operable program or a batch file

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp

I have php 8 installed on my windows 10 with the latest version of xampp (8.1), when I try to save a php file in my vscode I get the following messages:

1 - 'phpcs' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an operable program or a batch file.

2 - phpcs: Request workspace/configuration failed with message: Unable to locate phpcs. Please add phpcs to your global path or use composer dependency manager to install it in your project locally.

[image]

I already tried to add the following lines in settings.json and I was not successful:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

[image]

Comment: You need to install phpcs. You can do via composer.

Comment: yes, it is already installed, I used the command
 composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer

Comment: When you install locally, you will find it in vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin and put that path to your PATH environment. On global you need to look where it is installed then.